# mac mail sort by date newest at top by default

Tags: mail.app, sort

When opening mac mail I always get my mails sorted in the wrong order in the Date sent column i.e. oldest at the top. But like most people I want to have my mails sorted by the newest date on top by default.

Is it possible to configure mac mail to sort my mails by newest date at the top by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the sort by clicking on the table headers it should stay that way across launches.

Answer (score 1):

With the Date Sent column header is selected (blue), the default should be to sort with the newest at the top. If this isn't the case, **click the column header again** and the order will switch.
So, if it was oldest first before, it will now be newest first and vice-versa.